# Confused about Graph Theory Language

Tags: graph-theory, notation, terminology

I was confused about some of the wording in this definition I came upon:

Let G be a control flow graph (a control flow graph you can imagine as a directed graph) for program P.  A hammock H is an induced subgraph of G with a distinguished node V  in H called the entry node and a distinguished node W not in H called the exit node such that

1. All edges from (G - H) to H go to V.
2. All edges from H to (G - H) go to W.

To my understanding to create an induced subgraph you remove vertices and adjacent edges corresponding to those vertices. (G - H) in this situation I think means all the edges from graph G left over after removing the corresponding edges from graph H.  "go to V" I think means the edge in the directed graph points to V.  I'm not sure if I'm right about all of these.

I'm having trouble understanding what "(G - H) to H" and "H to (G - H)" mean.

Thanks a lot for you time.

Comment: You are correct about all of them. You can think of $H$ as an isolated subsystem in the graph with one input and one output for the whole subgraph, so it sort of acts like a single vertex.

Comment: You said G-H means "all the edges...".  Typically in graph theory one thinks of a graph as a set of *vertices*, not edges (of course edges are a part of the graph, but if we have to pick one set to represent the graph, it's usually the vertex set).  So H is an induced subgraph defined by a subset of vertices.  G-H is the complementary set of vertices.  If you think of H and G-H as vertex sets then the concept of edges from one to the other should make sense.

Comment: Thanks!  I get what a hammock graph is now.  Figure 1 from this paper was also helpful visualizing it http://syrcose.ispras.ru/2007/files/2007_01_paper.pdf